# Azure sentinel / Monitor- Is it possible to get Azure AD user profile details (usage location , Country or region ,Office) into azure sentinel logs?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitoring

I would like to know Is it possible to get Azure AD user profile details (usage location, Country or region, Office) into azure sentinel logs? what would be the Kusto query for that?

Answer (score 2):

This capability will be available as part of Azure Sentinel UEBA feature.
This is currently in private preview (soon to be public).

Once enabled, Azure Sentinel UEBA will sync your Azure Active Directory tenant (i.e. Cloud and/or synced AD users) and it will populate the IdentityInfo table with the user metadata (job title, department, manager..) and groups and roles membership.

an official blog will be published in a few weeks describing the solution.